# Constraints on the homology of amenable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-cohomology

*Edit (March 24): My first question has been answered nicely, but I am still looking for an answer to the second one.*

Due to the Kan–Thurston theorem, the homology of an arbitrary group can be anything you want.

Using the Rips complex, we can see that hyperbolic groups are $F_{\infty}$ and, if torsion-free, even of type $F$, i.e., there exists a model of $BG$ that is a finite CW-complex.

The other side of Bridson's [universe of finitely presented groups](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Non-positive-curvature-and-complexity-for-finitely-Bridson/d47a57a60cf5602ee193065546a0e420195d2a69) is where amenable groups live. I wondered about constraints that amenablility imposes on the cohomology of a group. More precisely, let me ask the following two separate questions.

Let $G$ denote a finitely presented torsion-free amenable group.

- Is $G$ always of type $F$?

(True for nilpotent groups, see Brown's book. In general, this is probably false or open: Wikipedia taught me that it is an unresolved conjecture to prove that Thompson's group $F$ is not amenable.)

- Can it happen that $H_{j}(G;Z)$ is non-trivial in a single degree $d$?

(For $d = 1$, we can obviously choose $G = \mathbf{Z}$, but I do not know any examples for bigger $d$.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is every finitely presented torsion-free amenable group of homotopical type F?

It's false even for metabelian groups.

For $i=1,2,3$, let $G_i$ be a copy of a solvable Baumslag-Solitar group, say $\langle t_i,x_i|t_ix_it_i^{-1}=x_i^2\rangle$. Start with $H=G_1\times G_2\times G_3$. It has a homomorphism $\phi$ onto $\mathbf{Z}$ mapping each $t_i$ to $1$ and each $x_i$ to $0$. Let $G$ be its kernel. Then $G$ is finitely presented, but not of type FP$_3$ / F$_3$.

This follows from the "FP$_m$-conjecture" for metabelian groups. Namely $H$ is not finitely presented by the Bieri-Strebel criterion [3], and $H$ is not FP$_3$ / F$_3$, as the "FP$_m$-conjecture" is known for $m=3$ in a semidirect product of two abelian groups [2], and also known in general when the Prüfer rank is finite [1].

Note: the exponent $2$ could be replaced with any number $\ge 2$, possibly depending on $i$. Also, $\phi_i(t_i)$ could be defined as any positive integer $n_i$, with the same conclusion (while if $\phi(t_1),\phi(t_2)>0$ and $\phi(t_3)<0$ the resulting kernel has type F).

---

[1] H. Åberg, Bieri–Strebel valuations (of finite rank), Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 52 (1986) 269–304.

[2] R. Bieri, J. Harlander, On the FP3-conjecture for metabelian groups, J. London Math. Soc. (2) 64 (2001)
595–610.

[3] R. Bieri, R. Strebel, Valuations and finitely presented metabelian groups, Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 41
(1980) 439–464.

Comment: (Note: taking $n$ copies of the Baumslag-Solitar and defining $H_n$ similarly, we get a metabelian group that is FP$_{n-1}$ and not FP$_n$. By the way, F$_n$ and FP$_n$ are equivalent for metabelian groups.)

Comment: "$F_n$ and $FP_n$ are equivalent for metabelian groups." - for the record, they're also equivalent for finitely presented groups.

Comment: @MattZaremsky could you give a reference?

Comment: @ARG this is certainly in Brown's book "cohomology of groups". (Homotopical property F$_n$ is equivalent to [FP$_n$ + finitely presented])

Comment: Yeah, it should be in Brown's book, and also in Geoghegan's book "Topological Methods in Group Theory". My favorite "reason" for (fin. pres. + FP_n)=(F_n) is that it's a group theoretic version of Hurewicz: (simply connected + homology vanishes)=(homotopy vanishes).

Answer (score 10):

Abels' groups provide simple examples of solvable groups that are finitely presented but not of type $F$. Given a ring $R$, define the group
$$A_n(R):= \left\{ \left( \begin{array}{ccccc} 1 &&&& \\ & d_1 && \ast & \\ && \ddots && \\ & 0 && d_{n-1} & \\ &&&& 1 \end{array} \right) \in \mathrm{GL}(n+1,R), \ d_1,\ldots, d_{n-2} \in R^\times \right\}.$$
Extending Abels' result, Brown proved that, for every prime $p$ and every $n \geq 1$, the (virtually torsion-free) group $A_n(\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$ is of type $FP_{n-1}$ but not of type $FP_n$, and it is finitely presented whenever $n \geq 3$.

Comment: Note: $A_n(\mathbf{Z}[1/p])$ is not torsion-free, but its normal subgroup of index $2^{n-1}$ of elements with positive diagonal is torsion-free.

Comment: @JensReinhold: I added a remark in my answer about your second question.

Comment: @AGenevois: About this thing for the second question, I think the Euler characteristic being zero just means that *if* the homology is concentrated in a single positive dimension, then the non-zero thing can only possibly be a Betti number of 1 in an odd dimension. (But OK, I see the question is phrased a little wrong, it should have said non-trivial homology in a single *positive* degree.) (Also, for the record, I have no idea whether an example exists with, e.g., $d=3$.)

Comment: @MattZaremsky: You're right, my comment is not so interesting...